# Can't select the datetime if more than min date in the datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker

I have a problem selecting the date more than today in the DateTime picker for reactJs. If I select more than today and time, then I click submit button, it will alert `Value must be 21/09/2022 10:02 PM or later.`

[image: img1]

```html
const formatIosDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const formatIosTime = moment(new Date()).format("HH:mm");
const newIosDateValue = formatIosDate + "T" + formatIosTime;
const [iosFormatWeeklyToDay, setIosFormatWeeklyToDay] = useState(newIosDateValue);
<Form.Control
  type="datetime-local"
  name="startDate"
  value={iosFormatWeeklyToDay} 
  onChange={(e) => {
    setIosFormatWeeklyToDay(e.currentTarget.value);
  }}
  min={newIosDateValue}    
/>
```

I am using formik to send the date.

```html
<Button
type="submit"
variant="primary"
disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
>
{formik.isSubmitting ? (
  <FormattedMessage id="GENERAL.SAVING" />
) : (
  <FormattedMessage id="GENERAL.SAVE" />
)}
</Button>
```

May I know how to remove this alert message, this alert message I don't want to use `Value must be 21/09/2022 10:02 PM or later.`

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `min={newIosDateValue} ` from the <Form.Control ... /> ?

Comment: Cannot remove this, because I want to set minimum date in the datepicker

Comment: Perhaps update that minimum date to be less than the current ISO time?  Because I have a feeling that that's what causing you this issue.

Comment: @HarshTuwar Do you have any solutions for this issue?

Comment: `myDate = new Date().setHours(new Date().getHours() - 5);` this should subtract 5 hours from the current ISO time.....You can convert that hours into ISO string by using this:- `newIsoDateValue = new Date(myDate).toISOString()`. Give it a try...